# create ajax contact form.

Tags: jquery, ajax, ajaxform

i created an ajax contact form, it has a problem with responseText. when i click the submit button to send data. instead to show the response text, it show like this.

`<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en-US" class="no-js"> <head> <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11"> <link rel="pingback" href="http://localhost/pomtech/jami/xmlrpc.php"> <!--[if lt IE 9]> <script src="http://localhost/pomtech/jami/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/js/html5.js"></script> <![endif]--> <script>(function(html){html.className = html.className.replace(/\bno-js\b/,'js')})(document.documentElement);</script> <title>Page not found &#8211; jami university</title> <link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//fonts.googleapis.com' /> ...`

**Ajax codes.**
here is some jQuery code that i used to get form data.

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   var form =jQuery('#ajax-contact');
  var formMessages= jQuery('#form_messages');
  jQuery(form).submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

 var formData=jQuery(form).serialize();
 jQuery.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   ulr: jQuery(form).attr('action'),
   data: formData
 }).done(function(response){

    // make sure message is success 
    jQuery(formMessages).removeClass('error');
    jQuery(formMessages).addClass('success');

    //set message text
    jQuery(formMessages).text(response);

    // clear form fields
    jQuery('#name').val('');
    jQuery('#email').val('');
    jQuery('#message').val('');
 }).fail(function(data){
       // make sure message is error     
    jQuery(formMessages).removeClass('success');
    jQuery(formMessages).addClass('error');


    // set message text
    if(data.responseText !== ''){
        jQuery(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
    }
    else{
        jQuery(formMessages).text('an error has been occured');
    }
 });  });  });
```

**HTML codes**

```
  <div id="form_messages"> </div>


<form id="ajax-contact" method="post" action="mailer.php">
<div class="field">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required="required">
</div>  
<div class="field">
   <label for="email">Email:</label>
   <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required="required">
</div>
<div class="field">
  <label for="message">Message:</label>
  <textarea id="message" name="message" required="required">

  </textarea>
</div>   
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="'.$recipient.'">
<input type="hidden" name="subject" value="'.$subject.'">

<div class="field">
  <input type="submit" name="contact_submit" value="Send" >
</div>
</form>
```

**mailer.php**

```
<?php echo "Hello world"; ?>
```

there is no need for more details but stackoverflow did not premit me to post my question with less information. so these context are belong to my question

Answer (score 1):

Change 'ulr' to 'url' in AJAX Call.

```
jQuery.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: jQuery(form).attr('action'),
   data: formData
})
```

Comment: but still i have such problem.

Comment: Then you might not have `mailer.php` file or it's location is different.